# What medical issues or procedures can cause denied medicals?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

Are there a lot of things that can cause a denied medical? Can fairly routine procedures be grounds for denial? (Please don't hate me for having 2 questions in one!)

Comment: You will find that there are lots of things that are clear cut, but that most of the potential issues are grey, and require evaluation. The general standard is the risk that a condition can result in physical or mental incapacitation at a bad time. So a procedure that results in little to no risk of incapacitation after recovery, you'll probably be ok, but you have to just disclose it and find out what happens. I've developed sporadic Afib, which is mostly an annoyance, as have no underlying heart disease. I had to disclose it and submit reports. Waiting to find out if I can keep flying.

Comment: Got it. I was worried about a few prior injuries but they’ve not been an issue since, and incapacitation isn’t an issue. That’s a really good way of explaining it, so thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its really no big secret, [the FAA publishes their full guide for AME's and you can read it if you like (all 514 pages...)](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/guide.pdf) and generally speaking it lists a lot of the disqualifying factors. They offer [various guides as well, all of which are public](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/).

If you are worried that something relating to you personally is grounds for denial you can [always reach out to an organization like AOPA for assistance.](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/medical-resources)

*Routine Procedure* is a fairly broad term and an answer cant really be provided since this can be highly case by case depending on what the procedure is.